# How to delete all messages that have URLs that are not www.youtube.com or www.twitter.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I am new here, and recently I have been facing a big problem with Discord Scam Links in my Discord server, I tried that:

```
if(message.content.includes("discordscam.com")) {
   message.delete()
   }
```

But this is a very bad way to fight scams since it will only delete one specific URL and not other ones, I realized that I should use RegExp, but, unfortunately, I don't understand how.

Comment: what happens if contents contain multiple sites like twitter AND discordscam?

Comment: @depperm it should delete the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because contents may include multiple urls, you'll need to check each word. First filter words to just any urls. Then from there check if any of the urls aren't twitter or youtube.

First regex is for url `/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()!@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/`

Next regex is for allowed urls `(youtube|twitter).com`

```js
// split contents by word, check each word
function shouldDelete(contents){
   
    let urlFilter = contents.split(' ').map(word => {
        let t = word.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()!@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/)
        return t?.length > 0 ? t[0] : null
    }).filter(url=>{
        if(!url || /(youtube|twitter).com/g.test(url)) return
        else
          return url
    })
    if(urlFilter.length > 0){
        return `"${contents}" should delete`
    }else{
        return `"${contents}" shouldn't delete`
    }
}

let sampleContents=[
  'twitter.com',
  'youtube.com',
  'discordscam.com',
  'discordscam.com and youtube.com',
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=emb_logo'
]

sampleContents.forEach(item=>{
    console.log(shouldDelete(item))
})
```

Comment: You may want to escape the `.` as it will match *any* character

Comment: actually yeah, thanks for a good answer

Comment: also, this will not consider things like `youtube.com.xyz`

Comment: thank you for your detailed and well-explained answer!

Comment: @asyncawait that is a dangerous URL according to my browser. I advise others to not follow it

Comment: @MrMythical, I think there must have been some miscommunication. My message was that this regular expression will say that `youtube.com.xyz` is an okay website when it is not. This site would be the subdomain `youtube` of the doman `com` on the top level domain of `xyz` which is not the desired target.

Comment: I'm just warning others in case they try to go to it

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps point you in the right direction!

I have a regular expression that is validating based on the string either having youtube or twitter, followed by `.com` and can not have any more periods afterwards.

```js
const urlTest = str => 
  /^.*(youtube|twitter)\.com[^.]*$/.test(str);
  
console.log(`
  testing "youtube.com"
  good? ${urlTest("youtube.com")}
  
  testing "twitter.com"
  good? ${urlTest("twitter.com")}
  
  testing "youtube.com.net"
  good? ${urlTest("youtube.com.net")}
  
  testing "https://somesite.com/nothing"
  good? ${urlTest("https://somesite.com/nothing")}
  
  testing "https://youtube.com/somethingelse"
  good? ${urlTest("https://youtube.com/somethingelse")}
`);
```

Comment: that's a good regexp, but how do I check if the link in the message is not youtube.com or twitter.com?

Comment: this would be good for testing a url once you manage to extract it, but I'm not familiar with discord api, so extracting the url is a different story.

Comment: oh okay, thank you anyway! :D